# Macbook pro grub boot help please!

Tags: boot, grub2, macbook

i got hold of a 2011 Macbook pro with the AMD hybrid GPU malarkey...
I have no intention whatsover to run osX so I managed to install Ubuntu using the guide here:
https://orville.thebennettproject.com/articles/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-2011-macbook-pro/

unfortunately my grub file looks nothing like the one described in the guide.... so once installed i am not able to boot.

please help!!!

Comment: I had a similar issue with my 13" mid-2009 Apple Macbook Pro and solved it by doing what I explain [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299955/389062)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "not able to boot", is it a black screen or something else?

Had this problem with my macbook and I figured that you will need to enter the **outb** codes in the grub config when booting.