# How do I get the grub menu to show on a MacBook?

Tags: grub2, 19.10, macbook, grub-efi

I've installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my MacBook (Mid-2010 a.k.a. Macbook7,1) as the only OS. Right now my system is working but it has a few issues. One of those issues is that I can't seem to get GRUB to show a menu no matter what I do. Right now, this is what my `/etc/default/grub` file contains:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto
```

When my computer boots, I see a non-blinking `_` symbol for about 5 seconds and then I see the normal kernel output that you seen when Ubuntu starts booting. If I press the `ESC` key when the `_` is showing, the boot will not continue and the screen is stuck like that until I forcibly power down the system by holding the power button.

A clue that I have noticed is that the grub menu works perfectly fine when booting from the USB installer. I've looked at the `grub.cfg` on the USB installer, and it has this line which seems absent from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on my Ubuntu install: `insmod efi_gop`

So given this info, how do I configure GRUB to show a menu?

Answer (score 12):

**SHORT ANSWER**

This **workaround** worked on my 13" Apple Macbook Pro mid-2009 running 64-bit XUbuntu 20.04:

1. Create a LiveCD of the *Ubuntu (i.e. Ubuntu, XUbuntu, KUbuntu...) distribution *just in case*.
2. Delete the `shim*.efi` file located at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/`
3. Use APT to purge (i.e. completely uninstall) the **shim** DEB packages (`shim` and `shim-signed`) from the system.
4. Delete the `grub` folder located at `/boot`
5. Install GRUB again (i.e. perform a "fresh" or "clean" GRUB install with a command such as `grub-install /dev/sda ; grub-install --recheck`).
6. Fix GRUB's default settings at `/etc/default/grub` in order to **[1]** activate GRUB's *console mode* and **[2]** *force* GRUB to show its menu for 3 seconds, under such *console mode*. You do this by basically setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`, `GRUB_TIMEOUT=3` and `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in `/etc/default/grub`.
7. Run `sudo update-grub` so these *fixed* default settings are applied to the "fresh" GRUB install.
8. Run `efibootmgr` in order to make sure that `ubuntu` (i.e. `grubia32.efi` or `grubx64.efi`, created and stored at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`) still is the default EFI boot loader option.
9. Reboot the system.
10. Boot from the LiveCD in case of problem.

---

**(VERY) LONG ANSWER: HOW TO PERFORM THE ABOVE PROCEDURES**

1. CREATE THE LIVECD.

   There are several ways to create a LiveCD. The most basic ones, in my opinion, consist of downloading the *Ubuntu LiveCD `.iso` file (e.g. `ubuntu-20.04-amd64.iso`) and then either using [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io) to burn it into a USB stick (flashdrive) or (if you have access to a Linux shell terminal such as `bash`) using `dd` to burn such `.iso` file into any external media (USB stick, writeable CD-ROM etc.). The [answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal) provide a quite detailed set of procedures about it.
2. DELETE THE SHIM EFI FILES.

   Once you've created your LiveCD and tested it to make sure that it's going to work if you happen to need it, open a shell terminal emulation window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> is a shortcut to it, but you can also run it from the *Applications* panel/menu or right-click a free area in the *Desktop* and then select the *Terminal* option) and then run `sudo su` in the terminal so you become the **root** user. Becoming **root** will spare you from having to use `sudo` on every shell command from this point on. After becoming **root**, delete the `shim*.efi` file (e.g. `shimia32.efi` for 32-bit systems, `shimx64.efi` for 64-bit systems) that is probably located at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. Assuming that the **shim** `.efi` file is indeed located at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`, it can be deleted by running this command in the terminal:

   ```
    rm /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shim*.efi
   ```

   - If the EFI partition isn't mounted, the command `mount /boot/efi` will likely mount it. If such command doesn't mount it, run `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,PARTLABEL |grep -i efi` to find your EFI partition (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) and then mount it (e.g. `mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi`). If the `/boot/efi` mount point does not exist, create it with the command `mkdir -p /boot/efi` and then mount the EFI partition at it (e.g. `mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi`).
   - Furthermore, once such EFI partition is mounted at `/boot/efi`, and assuming that the **shim** `.efi` file is at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`, a command like `thunar /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` or `nautilus /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` (depending on which file manager your system uses) will give you **root** access to such folder (e.g. `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`) directly from your file manager (windowed interface): this makes it easier to browse, find and then delete the **shim** `.efi` file (e.g. `shimx64.efi`).
   - ***WARNING*** If you're connected as **root** and accidentally delete the wrong file, such file is **lost forever** (it does **not** go to the trash bin). It's therefore advised that you pay a **lot** of attention on what you're doing so you don't end up rendering your operating system unusable/inaccessible.
   - In case you're wondering why you should delete the **shim** `.efi` file (i.e. the 32-bit `shimia32.efi` file or the 64-bit `shimx64.efi` file): GRUB's `.efi` file (i.e. the 32-bit `grubia32.efi` file or the 64-bit `grubx64.efi` file) is the appropriate one to use on a computer where *Secure Boot* is disabled. The shim version actually just provides a signed version of the GRUB `.efi` file version (because *Secure Boot* requires such signed version). But if you install *Ubuntu on a Mac with disabled *Secure Boot* (which is the frequent case), *Ubuntu adds the shim EFI file as the default option even though the Mac's firmware tells the bootlader to load the *unsecure* GRUB EFI file. So the solution is to delete the shim (*Secure Boot*) EFI file and then make the GRUB (*non-Secure Boot*) EFI file the new default one that must "interact" with the Mac's hardware at boot time.
3. PURGE THE SHIM DEB PACKAGES.

   After you delete the **shim** `.efi` file that was located at e.g. `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`, run APT to purge the **shim** DEB packages and therefore prevent future **shim** updates from creating the problematic `.efi` file again:

   ```
   apt-get purge shim shim-signed --allow-remove-essential -y
   ```
4. DELETE THE GRUB FOLDER.

   Now that you're rid of **shim**, it's time to get rid of GRUB: go back to your file manager window (e.g. Nautilus, Thunar...) and delete the `grub` folder that is likely located at `/boot`. If you don't find the `grub` folder in `/boot`, run the command `updatedb ; locate -i grubenv` to find the location of the `grubenv` file: this file is stored at the `grub` folder, thus if you find the location of the `grubenv` file you find the location of the `grub` folder.

   - If you prefer to delete the `grub` folder from the terminal (assuming that it's located at `/boot`), just run:

     ```
     rm -r /boot/grub
     ```

     ...and the `grub` folder will be deleted.
5. INSTALL A "FRESH" COPY OF GRUB.

   Assuming that GRUB was installed in your first SATA storage drive (i.e. `sda`), install it back there by running this command:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda ; grub-install --recheck
   ```

   If your EFI partition is located at e.g. `sda` (e.g. `/dev/sda1`), it's common practice to install GRUB in `/dev/sda`. If your EFI partition is located at e.g. `sdb` (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`), it's common practice to install GRUB in `/dev/sdb`. And so on.

   As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/145246/389062), it's also possible to use your LiveCD to install a "fresh" GRUB in your *boot disk* (e.g. `/dev/sda`). This method is particularly useful when your system's GRUB installer is damaged and you're temporarily unable to reinstall it through e.g. APT. I.e. for a 64-bit Intel Mac, the **root** installation command currently is `apt install grub-common grub-efi grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc-bin grub2-common`, but if it's not working on your system, you can always boot the LiveCD so GRUB is installed from the packages that are running from your LiveCD and then the new `grub` folder created in e.g. `/boot` is created by this LiveCD's GRUB.
6. FIX GRUB'S DEFAULT SETTINGS.

   If you don't have the Gedit text editor, install it by running the command `apt-get install gedit -y` and then run this command in order to edit GRUB's default settings file with Gedit:

   ```
   gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Once the Gedit window shows the contents of the `grub` file, remove the `#` character that is located at the left side of each one of the parameters `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE`, `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_TERMINAL`, and then modify their options so they become these:

   ```
   GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
   GRUB_TERMINAL=console
   ```

   - The `menu` option tells GRUB that it must create and show a menu when the computer is started or restarted.
   - The `3` option tells GRUB that it must wait 3 seconds before automatically booting the default operating system kernel, so the user has enough time to e.g. select a different kernel from the menu (if you prefer, you may either lower it to 1 or 2, or increase it to 4, 5 etc.).
   - The `console` option tells GRUB that it must ignore the graphics card's most appropriate driver and instead use a simplified VGA display driver that is much more basic but also much more compatible: it won't provide a fancy menu, but will provide a functional one that's more likely to work and be visible.

   When you're done making the above modifications, save the file and then exit the Gedit text editor.

   If you prefer to use the shell's standard text editor (which happens to be Nano), run `nano /etc/default/grub` instead of `gedit /etc/default/grub`.
7. APPLY THE CHANGES THAT WERE MADE IN GRUB'S DEFAULT SETTINGS.

   This one is easy. Just go back to the terminal and run this command:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

   The above command will read the content of `/etc/default/grub` and apply it into the settings of the "fresh" GRUB install, thus changing GRUB's behavior from this point on.
8. MAKE SURE THAT THE CORRECT BOOT EFI IS SELECTED.

   Assuming that your EFI partition is mounted at `/boot/efi` and the **shim** `.efi` file that you deleted was stored at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` (this is *Ubuntu's default location for its `.efi` files), check if the GRUB's `.efi` file is there:

   ```
   ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ |grep -i '.efi'
   ```

   Because Intel Macs are 64-bit computers, it's expected that a 64-bit *Ubuntu was installed on it, and that therefore a file named `grubx64.efi` is found by the command above. However, 32-bit systems should instead use a file named e.g. `grubia32.efi`, so in case your system is a 32-bit one, look for the 32-bit version of the GRUB `.efi` file.

   - If no GRUB `.efi` file is found, something's wrong and you're advised to install GRUB again (see STEP 5).
   - If the GRUB `.efi` file is found, then it's now time to check if the `ubuntu` EFI folder is selected as the default (i.e. first) source of `.efi` files (this precedence is important at boot time). In order to do it, run this command:

     ```
     efibootmgr
     ```

   The output must show something like this:

   ```
   BootCurrent: 0001
   BootOrder: 0001,0080
   Boot0001* ubuntu
   Boot0080* Mac OS X
   Boot0081* Mac OS X
   Boot0082* 
   BootFFFF*
   ```

   In my case, `ubuntu` is identified as `Boot0001*` (its number is `0001`), thus it's the one that needs to be the default option: from left to right, `BootOrder` must show `0001` (i.e. `ubuntu`) first. If this is not your case, fix it by running a command like this:

   ```
   efibootmgr --bootorder 0001,0080,0081
   ```

   This is going to make `0001` (i.e. `ubuntu`) the first boot option, `0080` (i.e. `Mac OS X`) the second one, and `0081` (i.e. `Mac OS X`) the third one (I'm yet to find what is the difference between `0080` and `0081`. Anyway...).

   - If your bootloader is placed at e.g. `/dev/sdb`, you must update the boot manager by running the command `efibootmgr --disk /dev/sdb`.
   - If `ubuntu` isn't the active boot, make it active with `efibootmgr -b 0001 -a`. See more e.g. [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples) or by running `efibootmgr --help`.
9. REBOOT THE SYSTEM.

   Reboot your system in order to check if all this long journey fixed things out. You may reboot it from the menu or by running one of these terminal commands:

   ```
   init 6
   ```

   or

   ```
   reboot
   ```

   or

   ```
   shutdown -r now
   ```

   or

   ```
   telinit 6
   ```
10. BOOT FROM THE LIVECD IN CASE OF PROBLEM.

    The standard way to boot from a LiveCD on a Mac (iMac, Macbook etc.):

    - Power the Mac off.
    - Turn it on again and immediately hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key.
    - Type the password (if any was recorded in it) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
    - Plug in your LiveCD USB stick, external DVD drive containing a LiveCD DVD, Mac's internal DVD drive containing a LiveCD etc. and wait.
    - Once the Mac reads the contents of the LiveCD, a new icon will show up on the screen. Select it with the arrow keys (<kbd>◀</kbd> and <kbd>▶</kbd>) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>return</kbd>).
    - From here there are many possibilities depending on what went wrong. You may e.g. want to [use your LiveCD to reinstall and/or update GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd). In the worst case scenario, you can use the LiveCD to backup your data (to e.g. an external drive) and then reinstall the *Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: This answer doesn’t have nearly enough upvotes. Thank you!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. It took me a lot of time to figure out how to get rid of this issue and one of the reasons is because I couldn't find a "complete" answer anywhere. This motivated me to share this solution so others can more easily get rid of the issue aswell. I'm glad to know that it helped you and I hope that it helps more people.

Comment: @YuriSucupira What to do if I am stuck at the ubuntu logo? I can't get access to a shell

Comment: @LinuxGeek There are lots of possible reasons why this is happening and it's impossible to cover all of them in a single comment, but some questions may help you, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035332/updated-to-18-04-pc-freezes-before-the-login-screen-ubuntu-logo, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04, https://askubuntu.com/questions/959471/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-splash-screen-during-boot and https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu. If none helps, I suggest you add a new question.

Comment: @LinuxGeek You can also boot from the LiveCD, add the `nomodeset` parameter in `/etc/default/grub` as explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/38782/389062, then run `sudo update-grub` from the LiveCD session and reboot. You can read more about the `nomodeset` parameter [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do).

Comment: When I ran grub-install it put the simx64 file right back (visible in the ls of step 8).  The behavior is different now, though.  It shows the invalid parameter error for only a second, then boots to the grub menu and goes on.  It used to hang at the invalid parameter error for a long time.

Comment: @absmiths `grub-install` only installs the GRUB bootloader to a device: it does not install Shim, which is different bootloader. In order to install Shim you have to run `sudo apt-get install -y shim-signed`.

Comment: @absmiths Shim is a _preliminary_ bootloader: when you start your computer, its firmware (a small piece of software in its hardware) asks for a signed EFI file in order to authorize booting. Such EFI file must be a Microsoft-signed one. Shim then provides such signed EFI file (a 32-bit `shimia32.efi` file or a 64-bit `shimx64.efi` file) to the firmware. The firmware then authorizes Shim to boot. Shim then transfers such authorization to GRUB (which is not Microsoft-signed). And then GRUB boots Ubuntu Linux by either loading its 32-bit `grubia32.efi` file or its 64-bit `grubx64.efi` file.

Comment: @absmiths Hence, if you still got Shim in your system, then Shim is not completely removed and you should make sure that all Shim DEB packages are indeed purged from the system. Moreover, run `sudo find /boot \( -iname 'shim*.efi' \)  -exec ls -l '{}' \;` in order to find where the remaining Shim EFI file is located and then delete it with a command such as `sudo rm /path/to/such/shim/efi/file`. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64

Comment: @YuriSucupira On MacPro 2013 6,1 with macOS + Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot worked fine for a year then perhaps some system update messed up grub. Now, I get stuck at the grub boot screen after I reinstall grub from LiveUSB with error msg like `... Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed : Invalid Parameter Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled`
If I remove the `shim*.efi` from `/mnt/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` using LiveUSB then I get the extra error msg `LoadImage failed: Not found DevicePath: PciRoot(0) ...... /\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` ... and a paragraph of hex numbers.
So?

Comment: @YuriSucupira I've also tried adding `nomodeset` to the grub config but the screen still gets stuck at grub boot msgs.

Comment: @Shah-G My workaround is designed to work on a Mac with a single OS (Linux), but you need dual boot. This complicates things. You're likely going to have to boot from the LiveUSB, mount the Mac's 1st disk's 1st partition (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) at `/boot/efi` and then copy its `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` to `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` so your Mac's firmware chip reads the EFI GRUB data from `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` and then boots. Resetting the NVRAM and PRAM may help, too (due to undesirable GPU driver save state data that may be inconveniently stored in your Mac's hardware).

Comment: @Shah-G Also check [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831161/dual-booting-os-x-or-macos-with-linux-without-refind). Edit: this is not related to kernel mode setting, thus using `nomodeset` does not affect the issue.

Comment: I've done both NVRAM reset and `bootx64.efi` replacement. Now it gives a blank black screen and nothing happens. I've tried advanced options kernel 5.8 (recovery mode). It says smt like address NOT found ... kernel panic.

Comment: @Shah-G Unfortunately, I can't replicate the issue because I'm not dual booting. I'm going to suggest another couple of things, here, but if my suggestions don't help you fix this I strongly suggest that you report this issue in that question that I mentioned about dual booting with OS X/macOS + Linux, because the people up there dealt with the same issue. [1] Use `efibootmgr` as explained in step 8 to make this new grub EFI file the default one, and [2] make sure that the original `mmx64.efi` is present in both `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/mmx64.efi` and `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/mmx64.efi`.

Comment: @Shah-G `mmx64.efi` is MOKManager, a utility that signs bootloaders with your Machine Owner Key. MOKManager calls `grubx64.efi`. If it fails to boot that EFI file due to e.g. a bad signature, it reports the issue. `grubx64.efi` is therefore the GRUB bootloader, responsible for loading Linux, while `mmx64.efi` just invokes `grubx64.efi`. And `bootx64.efi` is a fallback when everything else fails. If you copy `grubx64.efi` to `mmx64.efi` (after creating `mmx64.efi.bak`), such hack may circumvent a problem with your UEFI implementation and MOKManager (because it just boots directly from GRUB).

Comment: @Shah-G I forgot to mention, but I believe that reading the article hosted at https://www.happyassassin.net/posts/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/ is a good start to understand what UEFI is, what's the difference between EFI boot manager and EFI boot loader, and why Apple's firmware complicates things for Mac users who wish to dual boot. If your Mac's firmware has its EFI boot manager with Secure Boot off, then it must load any unsigned EFI file despite of MOK and MOK state, since signing keys in such case are not required to boot from any boot loader (i.e. EFI file).

Comment: Is there any disadvantage in removing shim? For me the other answer was enough to get into grub menu.

Comment: @jarno As I mention [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter#comment2209560_1279602), `shim` is not necessary on a Macbook with Linux, because a Macbook with Linux boots Linux with *secure boot* mode disabled but `shim` is made for booting Linux with *secure boot* mode enabled. So, in a nutshell: **for the moment, no**, there's no **immediate** disadvantage in keeping `shim`. However, there's no advantage, either, and a further `shim` update may cause you problems that you however won't experience if you preemptively remove `shim`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm experiencing the same issue with 20.04 on a MacBook Pro 5,5 (13" Mid-2009). Booting from the Ubuntu Live USB installer displays the grub graphical menu absolutely fine.

A workaround that is working for me, until someone is able to find the root cause, is to uncomment or add `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to `/etc/default/grub`, and run `sudo update-grub`.

You can at least see and make selections from the menu, it just isn't full-screen or look as nice. I have a suspicion this is more of an EFI setup issue as opposed to a grub one.

Comment: Same problem and same solution on a Macbook Pro 2011. Congratulations for finding this. Moreover I do not see any problem with the display. If you have display problem while booting, try resetting the PRAM.  `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="countdown" GRUB_TIMEOUT="4" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" GRUB_TERMINAL="console"` are my edits of `/etc/default/grub` to see the booting messages and have a count down allowing to press `ESC` to enter the GRUB menu if I want to.  Thus I am better set for booting problems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my MacBook Pro 2010 with Xubuntu 22.04:

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot and you should see the GRUB menu.