# Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter

Tags: boot, startup, macbook, moklistrt

I have a MacBook Pro and only use Ubuntu on it. I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.

Now when I start the computer it says:

```
Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create mokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled.
```

Does anyone know EXACTLY how I can fix this?? Step-by-step process I don't want to mess anything up trying to fix this.

Comment: For reference, here is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1867092).

Comment: A possible duplicate with an accepted answer: [How do I fix broken boot after shim update?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1277828/448153).

Comment: I answered this question at https://askubuntu.com/a/1299955/389062. Your question is pretty much a duplicate of the one that was asked there, except that in your case you see the MOK List error message while the other question only mentions a blinking `_` instead of the MOK List error message. But the source of the problem is fundamentally the same: `shimx64.efi` (a signed / "MOKlisted" *Secure Boot* version of `grubx64.efi`) being used in a computer whose EFI's Secure Boot mode is disabled and, therefore, requires `grubx64.efi` instead.

Comment: I had a similar issue with my 13" mid-2009 Apple Macbook Pro and solved it by doing what I explain [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299955/389062)

Answer (score 56):

You have to replace  `shimx64.efi` with `grubx64.efi` as follows:

```
sudo su -
cd /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
cp grubx64.efi shimx64.efi
reboot
```

Comment: Point of reference for others. This does not work for the same error message on a 2010 iMac (coreDuo). The error may be more subtle or the older machine may need an even older version of grub.

Comment: this works also on MacBook Air 2015 model, You are awesome sir, thank you

Comment: In KDE neon, the directory named above exists but does not contain the files. They are in `/boot/efi/EFI/neon`. i removed packages `shim` and `shim-signed` afterwards.

Comment: This fix works, but only until the next system update re-installs shimx64.efi. The "permanent" fix for me was to remove "shim" and "shim-signed" (`sudo apt remove --purge shim shim-signed`) and then reinstall-grub (`sudo update-grub2`).

Comment: How do I do this if I can't boot into an OS with a shell? I'm just stuck in a grub shell

Comment: @lennartVH01 same with me. I am stuck on the ubuntu logo.

Comment: This worked for ubuntu 21.04 on a thinkpad

Comment: @ThomasPerl: Thanks for this, I tried your commands and they seemed to work fine, but there's no change. (I can still boot just like before, but I also still get the "Failed..." message.) To clarify, is this something you should run after/in addition to the other instructions, or instead? (FWIW: Ubuntu Server 20.04.2, Mac Mini late 2009.)

Comment: As asked before, how to enter shell if OS doesn't boot in. I see Ubuntu purple screen and a mouse cursor, and can do nothing.

Answer (score 10):

This is caused by [Bug #1867092](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1867092) and the proposed workaround (see comment #23) is:

```
apt-get purge shim
grub-install /dev/sda1 #replace sda1 with the correct grub partition for you
```

That solution worked for me.

Note that the best voted answer to this question, which is copying `grubx64.efi` over `shimx64.efi`, will be undone with each shim update according to that bug page.

Comment: This worked great for me

Comment: I tried `sudo update-grub2 /dev/sda1` (as mentioned in a comment to another answer), but that did not work. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1` (as specified in this answer) did the trick though.

Answer (score 9):

Solution that works on my 2010 iMac. Install [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and make sure to boot from the option that specifies `grubx64.efi`.

Comment: This worked and it was as simple as `sudo apt install refind` .

Comment: well the message MokListRT: Invalid Parameter disappear by installing reFind, I still not sure this is the best solution, as my system is not multi-OS, reFind is simply useless otherwise than hidding the message.