# Stuck in Grub while trying to replace Pop OS with Lubuntu

Tags: grub2, uefi, lubuntu, bootloader

So I installed Pop OS on an old mac book air. Then I decided to wipe it off and install Lubuntu. However I could never find the bootable USB with the lubuntu iso in my boot menu. I know that pop os isn't using grub and instead the systemd init system. I don't know, however, if this has anything to do with it.

I then installed the boot-repair tool and made somechanges and rebooted it again. Now I'm stuck in Grub telling me that:

```
Failed to se MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
...
```

I can do an ls and get the following
`(proc) (hd0) (hd0.msdos1) (hd1) (hd1.gpt4) (hd1.gpt3) (hd1.gpt2) (hd1.gpt1)`

Within the hd0 I can list
`efi/ loader/ and some hash-like number`

Within efi I can then see
`Reovery-7DD.../ POP_OS... systemd/ boot/ Linux/ pop/`

It's just that I'm really list here. In first place I don't know why I could never find my bootable USB (I always just saw Pop OS and Pop OS recovery when hitting F7 when starting up). And now I'm completely lost.

I know there is this answer [Stuck at GRUB command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line), but still I'm not really making progress. I'd be thankful for any pointer to anything

Comment: I've not responded as I know little about Pop OS; however `systemd` exists in the Linux kernel, and `grub` is run by your machine before Linux is actually started (it's a boot loader and is run by the machine BIOS/uEFI firmware directly before Ubuntu or the OS starts). Grub firstly loads initrd (initial ram disk) then booted the Linux kernel (which will cause systemd to start)... I suspect Pop OS uses `grub` like Ubuntu does (I doubt it uses LiLo or another boot loader, though Ubuntu supports LiLo & other bootloaders too), but with a single OS the grub menu may not show unless a key is struck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invallid Parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invallid-parameter)

Comment: Thank you very much! What finally helped was just to use another version. I tried Mint 19.04 and I could easily start it from the flashdrive. I don't know what I did wrong. Sorry....