# Can't boot Ubuntu Server on Dell PowerEdge R710 + RAID10 (PERC 6/i)

Tags: grub2, 20.04, uefi, dell, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server (amd64, trying 20.04 LTS but could be any distro above 12.04, they all fail) on a Dell PowerEdge R710 with a hardware RAID10 build using PERC 6/i card. I'm using UEFI boot and the Virtual Disk of 4 TB has a GPT table with protective MBR.

For versions 18 and 20 of Ubuntu Server, with the live ISO, setup wizard fails me at **Storage scanning phase**, with an error telling that I can view full report, send to Canonical, go to a Root Shell or continue setup. If I choose continue, I can install the system smoothly as long as I do not use LVM, otherwise it will throw another error during system files copy and restarts the installation wizard.

Storage screen recognizes the RAID array with expected size (~ 4 TB) and can even auto partition it with default values. After reboot, I can't boot in the system. It falls into GRUB2 console with below error:

[image: Error says failed to set mok list r t, invalid parameter; could not create mok list r t, i gnu Grub version 2.04; import m o k states has failed, function import_mok_state() failed; after that it falls to a Grub bash screen]

- I used a flash drive with Ventoy to run the ISO;
- Setup creates a 512MB EFI partition at `/dev/sda1` and use the rest of the disk as `/dev/sda2` (3.6 TB);
- I tried legacy ISOs, setup runs fine but also won't boot, same GRUB screen end;
- `ls` gives me `(proc) (hd0) (cd0)`;
- `ls (hd0)` gives me `Device (hd0) - No known filesystem detected`;
- I have tried to copy `grubx64.efi` to `shimx64.efi` as suggested [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invallid-parameter)
- BIOS version of the server is 6.2.2, I didn't find a way to update it without a Windows system which I don't have access.

I ask for help because I'm very new at Grub and boot-related stuff, and although I'm learning about it right now, I have a critical problem to fix that require this boot to work. Any ideas will be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the partitions laid out? Do you just have `/dev/sda1` for the EFI and `/dev/sda2` for everything else?

Comment: @Matigo sorry it took long to answerd, I had /dev/sda2 for /root and /dev/sda3 for the rest of the RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot ubuntu from installation usb then from terminal run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

and then

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I already tried that, but the problem still lingered.