# stuck on boot - macbook pro 2011 - faulty AMD gpu

Tags: grub-efi, macbook-pro, i915, moklistrt

I followed this post:
[Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter)

I managed to replace the shimx64. Efi with grubx64. Efi, through LIVE Ubuntu.

Now only appears a " _ " on the left side of the screen and nothing more happens.
The graphic card from my macbook pro 2011 its faulty (AMD radeon), so I edited the grub (Run the i915) to install and to use the Live Ubuntu.

But now I have no idea what to do, my knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Been there! This "_" means that you have booted linux, but looking at a wrong display. Xserver is configured for now absent dGPU. You can switch to another terminal with some Alt+Ctrl+Shift+Fn[1-6] (I cannot remember the exact Ctrl-Shift thingy, and had to use USB PC keyboard), but only in text mode. Than you can debug display config, **OR** you can

Try disabling PCIe GPU entirely in grub.
Hit 'e' during GRUB select, find a string with insmod gzio and type in the following strings above it:

```
   outb 0x728 1
   outb 0x710 2
   outb 0x740 2
   outb 0x750 0
```

Press  Fn+F10 to boot.

If it boots successfully, modify grub permanently as in this tutorial: https://www.variadic.xyz/2020/06/15/ubuntu-2011mbp/.