# Poweredge R510 no grub recovery

Tags: boot, grub2, sudo, moklistrt

I successfully installed Ubuntu server 20.04 on Dell powerEdge R510, after some days I changed my administrative account privileges, and now I-m not in sudoers list.

During boot (UEFI) I can't access grub menu for entering in recovery mode. Tried pressing shift nothing, tried Esc key but the boot freeze at screen message:

```
Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create mokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled.
```

I need root privileges for restore my account and solve MokListRT problem (grubx64.efi).

I don't know how to enter in grub-recovery, no menu, only above message!!
Plese help me thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Solved entering in shell from installation media.
Thanks