# New issue encountered installing ubuntu. same bug different problem

Tags: grub2, macbook-pro, error-handling, debugging, moklistrt

was attempting to dual boot Ubuntu on an 2006 macbook pro intel core-duo. opted instead for full metal install and completely erased Mac OS. assuming it might clear the bug. i was wrong.

i was encountering the bug

```
Failed to set MokListRT: 
Invalid Parameter Could not 
create MokListRT: Invalid Parameter 
Importing MOK state has failed:
import mok_state() failed: 
Invalid Parameter Continuing 
boot since secure mode is disabled
```

i followed the solutions i found on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter) but my results were not the same. i tried several different scripts and solutions but got frustrated and failed to document. will do better going forward.

nothing much to document since I only have access to GNU/GRUB command line. single line bash with every script resulting in error command not found.

once installation was complete despite the bug i restarted, removed the usb drive as prompted and waited for it to load. i got the same failed parameter. same bug. so i logged into text using c key and got the GNU/GRUB command line. or text.

tried running scripts for solutions found relative to the mentioned bug above and also tried to clear BIOS this time and to no avail. cannot access BIOS

the error is not recognizing the commands and says it doesnt exist. not sure why I'm in GRUB dealing with exe files?

for example:
tried to run

```
sudo su *and all variations. ie -su , sudo etc
```

and am getting

```
error: cant find command 'sudo' *etc
```

i cant find any resources on this error and apologize if im wrong about that. I don't seem to have a functional OS to work with outside of recovery mode and GRUB

if anyone has any ideas i would love to try them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter)

Comment: as mentioned above i tried that solution already. no matter what i type into the GNU text i get error no such command exists. i restarted several times and now i see the EFI Boot drive. i click it and receive the MoKListRT failure again. option key no longer works for booting into GNU text. not sure how i can open a terminal window when i cant access the OS? also i confused cmd with option in my OP.

Comment: I'm not trying to run Windows programs in Ubuntu. I'm trying to boot Ubuntu from a usb drive onto a MacBook Pro. I'm encountering the MoKListRT Failure (bug) before and after the install. The Ubuntu install doesn't seem to be finalizing. upon restarting after the install to finalize I encounter the bug. I can access the GNU/GRUB single line bash. but non of the commands are recognized. I get error: command 'sudo etc' not found. nothing seems to work and idk how to access the BIOS to fix the problem.

Comment: exactly so not sure why it's being suggestes i try it? I need to find a way to access a shell and I can't. that's the issue isn't it? I'm hopeful someone will offer an actual potential solution. I'm not looking to argue about what my issue is or isn't. I'm not clear on what it is and need help finding out what it is. this seems redundant and unhelpful. I'm going to repeat the entire process and document it all next week. then I'll post a new ask.

Comment: working on a valid output for updating progress. ls command is working now. ls (hd0,1)/ outputs grub/efi/ I decided to test run VM Ubuntu on a Linux box and am looking over the files. I'm struggling with how to proceed. my machine is capable and my issue is not the bug but my lack of knowledge when it comes to the Grub shell command. I'm not sure how to access it. the bug is my next issue and I'm looking forward to fixing it. sorry if this output should be updated in my OP. I just don't want to be a pain and hope it's worthy of a response. my machine my problem. your guidance is much kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the MoKListRT bug but when I reboot holding ALT I get 2 efi drives and one of them still has the bug. what is the second EFI drive? I can't help but think there is an issue here that is in need of some guidance. the EFI drive on the left looks like a mac drive and the second one is the yellow Linux drive. they both boot Ubuntu but since booting into the first drive it's been buggy. now I'm forced to use my password which is fine just not sure why it's suddenly making the request.