# Cannot boot fresh Ubuntu 20.04 on Mac due to Failed to Set MokListRT?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, macbook, moklistrt

I have installed

Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS amd64

on a MacBook Pro 15" 2009

Not a dual boot, simply erasing disk for Ubuntu-only laptop.
Installation went smoothly.

After rebooting, I am getting following warning:

```
Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create mokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled.
```

After a moment Ubuntu purple screen appears, there is mouse cursor as well, but nothing happens from that point.

OS is unusable, I am not able to enter shell, not able to ALT+F2 into no-gui as well. Therefore I am not able apply to apply fixes described in this popular Q: [Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter).

(Please do not mark as a duplicate. OP there could enter OS to apply fixes, it was also caused by an upgrade, not a fresh installation.)

When trying to enter "EUFI Firmware Settings" from USB started GNU GRUB 2.04 it errors with:

```
can't find command `fwsetup'.
```

How to further proceed to make Ubuntu working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved doing following steps.

Installing Ubuntu 22.04 (most likely not essential as it was still not booting properly).

Entering Ubuntu recovery mode, sudo editing /etc/default/grub, adding nomodeset cmdline, updating grub, and restarting machine.