# Macbook Pro 7.1 Faild to Set MoKListRT

Tags: boot, macbook, macbook-pro, moklistrt

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS on to an old MacBook Pro 7.1, I followed the instruction on installing Ubuntu as the only operating system and all went well with no error but on booting the new installation I get the following errors.

```
Failed to set MoKlistRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create MoKlates has failed: import_mok_state0 failed
: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled
```

System then gives a blank screen and hangs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same machine running the latest version, has run without any issues for 3 months. Update and upgrade Yesterday and no safe mode set on bootup
MokListRt failed..... It eventually starts up bot can not run $sudo mukutil --reset as machine does not support secure boot. Something is screwed in the latest release

Comment: Similar setup, similar senario - same issue - Failed to set MoKListRT:Invalid Parameter Could not create MoKListRT:Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed:import_mok_state0 failed: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled_ any answers ?? I've just noticed a few new threads with the same issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280431/macbook-pro-failed-to-set-moklistrtinvalid-parameter https://news2.x-itm.com/macbook-pro-failed-to-set-moklistrtinvalid-parameter/

Comment: I had a similar issue with my 13" mid-2009 Apple Macbook Pro and solved it by doing what I explain [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299955/389062)