# MacBook Pro: Failed to set MoKListRT:Invalid Parameter

Tags: boot, 20.04, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my MacBook Pro 2010 (it was playing dead, so I helped it along with Ubuntu). I get this message on the screen when it's powered on and then it goes on to start the desktop.

```
Failed to set MoKListRT:Invalid Parameter 
Could not create MoKListRT:Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed:import_mok_state0 failed: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled_
```

Is this crucial for the operation of Ubuntu or not important?