# After Ubuntu upgrade to 20.04 PC boots directly to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have HP Pavilion laptop configured to dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 10. After I have upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04 grub2 menu does not appear and PC boots directly to Windows.

I have tried to fix the problem by using [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) without success. As suggested in the [boot-repair-disk report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hf9QrWCBYG/) I have executed as administrator the command: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`.
Before I launched boot-repair-disk I have disabled Fast Boot by executing command `powercfg -h off` as administrator.

When I boot the PC in upper left corner of the display is printed 'booting in insecure mode' (although the boot in my PC is in secure mode) and then it starts to boot Windows.

Before the upgrade Fast Boot has been enabled and if I remember correctly also 'booting in insecure mode' was displayed before the grub menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the solution](https://medium.com/@leijerry888/get-grub-menu-back-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-dab5de5afc37):

Launch boot-repair-disk -> advanced options -> edit GRUB configuration file

This will view `grub` configuration file and show its location. Open an other terminal and edit `grub` file:
add the line

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
```

and remove the comment from line

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
```

Save the `grub` file and continue boot-repair-disk by clicking apply button.

Comment: Very similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220175/how-do-i-get-the-grub-menu-to-show-on-a-macbook